# React on server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm able to render react from my server but i can't use any properties on my component.

Here is my code

```
var SiteComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-component">
        <span>You are searching for: TEST</span>
        {{this.state.secondsElapsed}}
      </div>

    );

  }

});

var MySiteComponent = React.createFactory(SiteComponent);

var App = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return MySiteComponent({prop: 'value'});    
  }

});

module.exports = App;
```

The state break everything. To be fair i use another factory after this code to render everything. It works but i can't use props or state.

```
function react(Component) {
  var ReactApp = React.createFactory(Component, {test: '1010'});
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(ReactApp());
}
```

The test 1010 was to show something on my properties but it is not working

Comment: well it was due to webpack :/

Answer (score 0):

```
function react(Component) {
  var ReactApp = React.createFactory(Component);
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(ReactApp({test: '1010'}));
}
```

`props` should be passed when you render component, not on factory create

Comment: Thanks  for the feedback :)